# Голосовой сайт

Tags: php

Как я могу сделать. Сайт закладок: захожу я  на [zaklDaria.ru](http://zaklDaria.ru) и говорю в микрофон "открыть гугл". И открываеться гугл.

Вот у меня есть вот такое:

```
sh apt-get install sox
apt-get install flac

#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]; do
     rec -q -c 1 -r 16000 current.wav silence 1 0.3 3% 1 0.3 3%
     flac -f -s current.wav -o current.flac
     php texttocmd.php
done

<?
$file_to_upload = array('myfile'=>'@current.flac');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=ru-RU");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$cmd_matrix = array(
 array(array("откр", "гугл"), "код открытия гугл я хз"),
    array(array("откр", "яндек"), "код открытия яндекса я хз")
        );

$json_array = json_decode($result, true);
$voice_cmd = $json_array["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"];

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($cmd_matrix); $i++ )
{
        $ok = 1;
        for ( $k = 0; $k < count($cmd_matrix[$i][0]); $k++ )
        {
                if ( !preg_match("/".$cmd_matrix[$i][0][$k]."/", $voice_cmd) )
                $ok = 0;
        }
        if ( $ok == 1 )
        echo $cmd_matrix[$i][1];
}

?>
$voice_cmd = $json_array["hypotheses"][0]["utterance"];

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($cmd_matrix); $i++ )

{
    $ok = 1;
    for ( $k = 0; $k < count($cmd_matrix[$i][0]); $k++ )
    {
            if ( !preg_match("/".$cmd_matrix[$i][0][$k]."/", $voice_cmd) )
            $ok = 0;
    }
    if ( $ok == 1 )
    echo $cmd_matrix[$i][1];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Чтоб передать на сервер голос можно воспользоваться плагином [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/index.html).

1. Указываете ему host куда слать файл с записанным с микрофона звуком. (см. [пример](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/example1.html)).

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     //Настройка пути куда слать
     $.jRecorder({host : 'http://zaklDaria.ru/acceptfile.php?filename=current.wav'});
     //По нажатию кнопки с id="record" начинаем запись
     $("#record").click(function(){
       $.jRecorder.record(30); //30 секунд записи максимум
     });
     //По кнопке с id="stoprecording" останавливаем запись и сразу отсылаем на сервер файл
     $("#stoprecording").click(function(){
       $.jRecorder.stop();
       $.jRecorder.sendData();
     });
   });
   ```
2. На сервере ловите его. acceptfile.php:

   ```
   $upload_path = dirname(__FILE__). '/';
   $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
   $fp = fopen($upload_path."/".$filename.".wav", "wb");
   fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));
   fclose($fp);
   ```
3. Запускаете перекодировку во flac там же.

   ```
   system('flac -f -s current.wav -o current.flac');//как-то так, если честно не в курсе как надо
   ```
4. дальше вызываете texttocmd.php где этот flac шлется гуглю, он его распознает, возвращает вам текст, по тексту у вас идет уже проверка результата, выполняется действие. это у вас уже есть.

Т.е. изначальный bash-скрипт у вас слушал эфир 30 секунд, затем конвертировал записанный звук, вызывал php. А тут надо наоборот, ждать файл от клиента на сервер, в php его принимать, конвертировать через внешний вызов конвертера, потом слать в гугль...

Comment: @Дарья Сереброва никто не говорил, что будет просто =)
Задавайте вопросы на каком этапе и что не понятно.  

Изначально вам надо понять, что исходный скрипт работает на одной машине и php и звук с микрофона снимается на ней же и действия выполняются на ней же.

У вас же задача разделить выполнение на две части. Первая часть - клиентская, создает звуковой файл и передает его на сервер. Вторая часть - сайт, который обрабатывает взятый у клиента звуковой файл, отправляет запросы гуглю, выдает результат опять клиенту. 

Сложности будут фактически на каждом этапе. Может быть и неподъемная задача.

Comment: Попробуйте поэтапно реализовать то, что в ответе. Добейтесь сначала сохранения файла на сервере. И т.д....   
Если честно, не считаю решаемую проблему достойной реализации. Я бы подождал html5 audio api для начала, во вторых на гугль завязываться очень слабое звено, скорость ответов, правильность распознавания и т.д. Мне, например, не удалось записать с ноутбучного микрофона голос, чтоб его гугль распознал (распознал сколько нибудь правильно), с гарнитурой наверное будет лучше. в любом случае такой сайт скорее для персонального использования и следовательно интереса не представляет. имхо.

Comment: Я вот видела на недо студии для созданиЯ программ с использованием php.
Devel studio там мальчик сделал программу которая соединяеться с гугло распазноёт голос и присылает ответ))) Как так мальчишки помогите =(

Comment: Прошу помогите мой cкайп bukvoedziga готова если нужно заплаить

Comment: Извините, я пас. Если кто-то другой откликнется...

Comment: Умаляю помогите

Comment: @Дарья Сереброва Здесь не приветствуются подобные предложения.